# Why is my TextField clearing in emulator but not on my Galaxy?

Tags: android, flutter

I made a simple list app, and after adding an item (onSubmitted) the textfield should be cleared so you can enter a new item. This works fine on the Android emulator, but not when I build and install it on my Galaxy S9+. Then the text is not cleared when I submit, but if I submit a second time it works.

So the first time the textfield is submitted the clear() function is ignored, the second time it works. I tried playin around with the focus node to see if that does anything, but nope. Any ideas what it could be?

```
  void _submitData(ListController listState) {
    var description = _descriptionController.text;
    listState.addItem(description);
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
    _descriptionController.clear();
  }
```

Comment: try reinstalling the app

Comment: That I have done many times of course. Also trying to omit the requestFocus, or running that after clear. Also tried to assign just an empty string. Same result.

Comment: try wrapping `_descriptionController.clear()` in `setState`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but no luck. I guess there is something weird going on further down the sack.